# Not able to reset my password

Tags: passwords

I am not able to reset my password. It takes me to the security challenge screen, I enter the right answer. Then, it takes me to the login screen and prompts me to enter the password. It is not allowing my to reset the password.

If my administrator tries to reset the password, I get this message:

> Your administrator has reset your password. However, your password
>   cannot be reset at this time.
>
> If you have any questions, please contact the salesforce.com
>   administrator for your company.

Comment: Please check the below link https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000205687&language=en_US                                                                    It requires minimum 1 day password lifetime..

Comment: As of 2018-03-01, the minimum 1 day password lifetime setting seems to be on despite not having the setting set.  I believe this is a SalesForce bug.  I have tried all of the suggestions, including resetting the password through APEX, and it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search of the error shows that this is due to an administration setting requiring passwords have a [1 day lifetime.](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000205687&language=en_US)  It may be worth flagging this with your Admin to either disable this feature by going to...

> Setup > Administer > Security Controls > Password Policies
>   Require a minimum 1 day password lifetime

... or waiting until that 1 day lifetime has expired.

Thanks!